# Is it possible to customize user profile URLs based on a custom profile field?

Tags: 6, users, uri

At the moment, my user profile URLs are changed in the standard way with pathauto, e.g.:

`/users/user.name`

However, I have different types of users (e.g. students, faculty, staff, etc.).

I would like the URL of each user's profile page to reflect that, e.g.:

- `example.org/students/user.name1`
- `example.org/faculty/user.name2`

The user type is set in a custom profile field: `profile_user_type`.

Is it possible to customize the URLs based on a profile field (in Drupal 6)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Pathauto uses the tokens provided by the [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module, you could use the [Token Profile](http://drupal.org/project/token_profile) module that implements tokens which return the value of user profile fields.

Comment: This is perfect!  I was wasting time trying to do it by hand in PHP!  I tested it and it is exactly what I was looking for.